# Import NPM packages in Odoo

Tags: npm, odoo

I'm trying to add couple of [npm packages](https://docs.safe.global/learn/safe-core/safe-core-account-abstraction-sdk/auth-kit) and use them in Odoo.

Having trouble importing them, tried following this [example](https://blog.bitbriks.com/create-react-module-in-odoo-as-standalone-app/), but no luck is this even possible in Odoo?

I installed the packages using the following command.

> npm install @safe-global/auth-kit @web3auth/base @web3auth/modal @web3auth/openlogin-adapter

This was one of the ways I tried importing them but none of them worked.

```
/* @odoo-module */
import { SafeAuthKit, SafeAuthProviderType } from '@safe-global/auth-kit';
```

```
odoo.define('todo.safe-global', function (require) {
const { SafeAuthKit, SafeAuthProviderType } = require('@safe-global/auth-kit');
});
```

Console Output

```
Missing dependencies: 
['@safe-global/auth-kit']
```